# How to associate the movement of objects

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, transforms

How to associate the movement of objects
ex：a（0，0，0）——A（x，x，0）
b（0，0，0）——B（-1/x，-1/x，0）

Comment: For a linear relationship, you can use a transformation constraint.  The relationship you show is not linear, but you can use a driver (in "scripted expression" mode) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using drivers:

Hover over a transform value (in my example X scale), press right mouse button and choose "copy as new driver".

Then over over the destination transform value (in my example X scale of object B), right mouse button, paste driver.

Then RMB again > edit driver > change the type from average value to scripted expression and type in any Python expression you need.

In case of Booleans, 0.0 is false, any other value is true.

[image]